# Error while converting textbox content to DateTime format in C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, culture

Hi i am developing an application, in that i required to store date in sql server 2005 database which is retrieved from a textbox in front end. In front end, user is allowed to pick a date from JQuery UI DatePicker plugin.

Error I am getting is as follows:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Code i have is:

```
db.eventDate = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text, new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat);
```

Comment: be sure that the input is the correct format you are trying to convert to for the specified cultureinfo. what is the input format you are providing?

Comment: for ex: if i choose a date from the JQuery UI Datepicker, it would be like 14/04/2014 in textbox. I am trying to convert that textbox data (i.e., 14/04/2014) to a DateTime Format.

Comment: Right. this is exactly why it is not working - your format is a UK format. you need to give it the uk format so it can parse it to the correct datetime format in this case then convert it to a us format. however in the jquery ui picker I am sure you can set the default input type/format to be en-us which will then correctly set the format to a us format and then your parsing will work correctly.

Comment: while debugging the code i came to know that, textbox date is in format of 14/04/2014 and after converting it to a DateTime type it will remain like 1/1/0001 12:00 AM

Comment: yes because that is the default value when it cannot parse (I believe). like I said, do as I suggested

Comment: Hi @Ahmed, i thank you for your suggestion, but to be frank i tried as you told but no effect. So kindly can you send a snippet of that particular.

Comment: Hey Ahmed, I really thank you very much... since your suggestion worked for me. Thank you dude...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
string yourDate = txtDate.Text;
string formattedDate = yourDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(formattedDate , "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

you better use `DateTime.ParseExact` with the correct date time format you set to date time picker

for example if the format is `"MM/dd/yyyy"` you can do as below

```
db.eventDate =  DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Hi @Damith, I tried your code too. Now i am getting error like <prev><code>The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.</code></prev>

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Working fine for me..

```
Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat);
```

or

```
Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
```

Comment: Hi Jameem, Thanks for your immediate response. I have tried your suggestion but still i am getting same error.

Comment: In database it is 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM by default. In my application user will pick date from JQuery UI date picker and it would be in the form 14/04/2014 and i am trying to convert this data from textbox to a valid DateTime type in code behind before inserting into database.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use DateTime.TryParse(expression) or wrap your call to DateTime.Parse in a try/catch block. Just out of interest, can you post some example dates you're converting ? They are in US format, right ?

Comment: Incorrect. having a try catch block around DateTime.TryParse will not throw an exception. TryParse does just that - tries to parse the given datetime value and returns true if success or false if not successful.

Comment: Please re-read what I wrote, I said "wrap your call to *DateTime.Parse* in a try/catch block", not DateTime.TryParse

Answer (score 0):

Hope following code helps you.

```
        Dim dt As New DateTime
        Dim txtDateFromUser As String = "04/09/2014"

        If DateTime.TryParse(txtDateFromUser, dt) = True Then

            Dim connStr As String
            connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("youConnectionStringName").ConnectionString

            'Insert into database
            Dim sqlconn As New SqlConnection
            sqlconn.ConnectionString = connStr
            Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("insert into tblDateTime (dtTestDate) values ('" + dt.ToString() + "')")
            sqlconn.Open()
            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconn
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End If
```

Here is the test table I've used:

```
        create table tblDateTime (dtTestDate datetime)
```

Comment: Nothing happened:( textbox date is getting converted to a default date 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM I don't know how to come out of this error. And morething, in database it's data type is datetime only.

Comment: what is the date string you're getting from the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

i simply changed the date format of JQuery UI DatePicker in my code. Before it was in UK format so i was getting error while saving data to database. But once i change it to US format it working fine.

I thanks for everyone who reviewed my question and suggested me the answers.